# Finding Actes notariés (Notarial Acts) when Notary's name is known?

Tags: 20th-century, canada

I have found an entry for a marriage in one of the Répertoires de notaires (Notarial Repertoires) in Ancestry's database Quebec, Canada, Notarial Records, 1626-1935 and I am trying to find the corresponding marriage contract.

Ancestry's [record page](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=61062&h=8060682&ssrc=pt&tid=86489741&pid=410115639798&usePUB=true) says:

> ```
> Name:     Frédéric Cormier
> Record Date:  24 juin 1902 (24 Jun 1902)
> Record Place:     Montréal, Québec (Quebec), Canada
> Inferred Marriage Year:   1902
> Notary:   Joseph-Alfred Nadeau
> Notarial Act Number:  6862
> Record Type:  Contrat de Mariage (Marriage Contract) (Marriage)
> Record Description:   Mariage
> Participants:     
> Name
> Frédéric Cormier
> Emma Tétreault
> ```

Sharing link to [the original image](https://www.ancestry.com/sharing/11240817?h=8a4b15&utm_campaign=bandido-webparts&utm_source=post-share-modal&utm_medium=copy-url) of the Répertoire (no sub should be required).

Ancestry gives this for the Source information:

> Source Citation
>
> Bibliothèque et Archives nationales du Québec; Montréal, Quebec,
>   Canada; Collection: Archives des notaires du Québec; District:
>   Montréal; Title: Nadeau, Joseph-Alfred (1900-1910)
>
> Source Information
>
> Ancestry.com. Quebec, Canada, Notarial Records, 1626-1935 [database
>   on-line]. Lehi, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2016.
>
> Original data:
>
> Fonds Cour Supérieure. Greffes de notaires. Bibliothèque et Archives
>   nationales du Québec, Montréal, Québec, Canada.

I am trying to see if the contract corresponds to the same couple in this marriage (record from the Droin collection):

[Quebec, Canada, Vital and Church Records (Drouin Collection), 1621-1968](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=1091&h=1191173&tid=86489741&pid=410115639798&usePUB=true&_phsrc=XXR3762&_phstart=default&usePUBJs=true)

> ```
>  Name:    Frederic Cormier
>  Spouse:  Emma Tetreau
>  Event:   Mariage (Marriage)
>  Marriage Year:   1902
>  Marriage Location:   Richelieu, Québec (Quebec)
> ```
>
> Source Information
>
> Ancestry.com. Quebec, Canada, Vital and Church Records (Drouin
>   Collection), 1621-1968 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA:
>   Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2008.
>
> Original data: Gabriel Drouin, comp. Drouin Collection. Montreal,
>   Quebec, Canada: Institut Généalogique Drouin.

Links to the shared images: [page 1](https://www.ancestry.com/sharing/11240889?h=ef2dcc&utm_campaign=bandido-webparts&utm_source=post-share-modal&utm_medium=copy-url) and [page 2](https://www.ancestry.com/sharing/11263133?h=67d222&utm_campaign=bandido-webparts&utm_source=post-share-modal&utm_medium=copy-url) of the church register entry.

I want to find the Actes notariés (Notarial Acts) corresponding to this entry, but the Actes notariés (Notarial Acts) of this notary don't appear to be on Ancestry or FamilySearch.

When I use the Browse function on Ancestry, I don't see Joseph-Alfred Nadeau in the list for Montréal:

[image]

Similarly I don't see Nadeau's name in the collection of [Quebec Notarial Records, 1800-1920](https://familysearch.org/search/image/index?owc=7L4Z-1G9%3A45164701%3Fcc%3D1471015) on FamilySearch.

What are some good search strategies for finding out which repository might hold the records of a particular notary, when the notary's name and the record date and location are known?

Answer (score 3):

Gail Dever posted instructions on her blog, Genealogy à la carte, on September 1, 2017: "[How to order a notary record from the Quebec Archives after finding it in an index on Ancestry](http://genealogyalacarte.ca/?p=20640)"

She explains how to take the information from the répertoire on Ancestry and search for the corresponding acte from Ancestry's partner, the **Bibliothèque et Archives nationales du Québec (BAnQ)**.

She says that you need to:

> Take note of the Record Date, Record Place, Notary, Notarial Act Number, Record Type, and all Participants.

At BAnQ, you can select English (if necessary) and then open an online request form to get digital copies of the record.  Gail says "The least expensive format is PDF file at 25 cents per page, and this is the version most genealogists will find useful."

You won't be required to give credit card information until after you get an email advising your order is ready.

> Call the number provided in the email. If you live outside Montreal, it
> will be a long-distance call. After you dial the number, you will
> hear a recording in French providing instructions. Without listening
> to the recording in its entirety, enter the four-digit extension
> number, which will take you to User Services where someone will answer
> your call.
>
> After you briefly explain why you have called, you will be asked to
> provide your credit card information. Payment is by credit card only.

If you live outside Montreal, and don't have a plan for international calling on your landline or cell, consider the cost of the call to Canada while budgeting.

Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the post for links to previous articles on this collection.

---

Further reading: [handout](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/img_auth.php/4/4f/Skimming_the_Surface_A_Look_into_Quebec_Notarial_Records_J_Kanyuck_Nov_2020_JMR.pdf) from the FamilySearch Class *Skimming the Surface: A Look Into Quebec Notarial Records*, presented via the Family History Library in November 2020 by Jacqueline Kanyuck.