# Name of the church for this parish register?

Tags: palaeography, canada, parish-register

This is a slip that identifies the parish register for the marriage of Frédéric Cormier and Emma Tétreault (see the related question [Finding Actes notariés (Notarial Acts) when Notary's name is known?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13131/1006)).

The register is from Notre Dame de (something) in the Diocèse de Saint-Hyacinthe, but I cannot make out the name of the parish.  The locality on the record page is Richelieu, Québec.

[image]

Using Ancestry's browse function doesn't reveal the name of the parish. I'd like to find a list of parishes in the diocese, or a list of parishes in the Drouin collection, where I could pick out the name of the parish from a list.

The title page of the register:

[image]

Wikipedia has an article about [Notre-Dame-de-Bon-Secours Chapel](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13131/1006) in Montreal:

> The Notre-Dame-de-Bon-Secours Chapel (chapelle Notre-Dame-de-Bon-Secours, "Our Lady of Good Help") is a church in the district of Old Montreal in Montreal, Quebec. One of the oldest churches in Montreal, it was built in 1771 over the ruins of an earlier chapel.

Does the archive slip say "Notre Dame de Bonsecours"? How can I find out more about where this parish register came from, and where this parish is located?

Answer (score 2):

According to the site [ORIGINIS](http://www.originis.ca/paroisse_richelieu.html), there is a parish Notre-Dame-de-Bonsecours in the municipality of Richelieu:

> Richelieu (Notre-Dame-de-Bonsecours)
>
> ```
>  Paroisse (Parish): Notre-Dame-de-Bonsecours 
>  Municipalité (Municipality): Richelieu 
>  MRC/Territoire équivalent (MRC / Equivalent Territory): Rouville 
>  Diocèse (Diocese): Saint-Hyacinthe
>  Adresse (Address): 750, 1ère rue, Richelieu Coordonnées: 45.445971, -73.256502
>  Ouverture des registres (Opening of the registers): 5 octobre 1868
> ```

(English equivalents of the fields are from Google Translate).